# Declaring Maps with typescript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, typescript

```
private itemsMap: Map<Array<string>,string> = new Map([
    [['shp'], 'Shapefile'],
    [['doc', 'docx'], 'Microsoft Word']
]);
```

Typescript doesn't like this, it gives me: "Argument of type '(string | string[])[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<[{},{}]>"

This is a valid way to declare a "Map literal" though.  Is there a way to do this that isn't going to cause an issue?

Comment: Is a list (`A[]`) directly an `Iterable<A>` in TS? Can you assign `var Iterable<String> foo_iter = ["foo"]`?

Comment: Yes:  `private a: Iterable<string> = ["a"];` is valid as far my ts compiler is concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What TypeScript version are using?  This appears to work correctly with the current TypeScript version (currently 2.2.x).

[See this playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20itemsMap%3A%20Map%3CArray%3Cstring%3E%2Cstring%3E%20%3D%20new%20Map(%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5B%5B'shp'%5D%2C%20'Shapefile'%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5B%5B'doc'%2C%20'docx'%5D%2C%20'Microsoft%20Word'%5D%0D%0A%5D)%3B%0D%0A)